# MACD + histogram default tradingview

Tags: pine-script, trading, tradingview-api, strategy-pattern

Hello can anyone help me I'm new at making indicators can anyone give me the default code of the macd in tradingview like with the histogram color buying or selling pressure weakening. thanks

I've tried it multiple times replicating the default macd but the histogram is my problem it's just red and green not strong green then lightening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can click on the `{}` icon to get the source code.

[image]

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Moving Average Convergence Divergence", shorttitle="MACD", timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
// Getting inputs
fast_length = input(title="Fast Length", defval=12)
slow_length = input(title="Slow Length", defval=26)
src = input(title="Source", defval=close)
signal_length = input.int(title="Signal Smoothing",  minval = 1, maxval = 50, defval = 9)
sma_source = input.string(title="Oscillator MA Type",  defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
sma_signal = input.string(title="Signal Line MA Type", defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
// Plot colors
col_macd = input(#2962FF, "MACD Line  ", group="Color Settings", inline="MACD")
col_signal = input(#FF6D00, "Signal Line  ", group="Color Settings", inline="Signal")
col_grow_above = input(#26A69A, "Above   Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_fall_above = input(#B2DFDB, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_grow_below = input(#FFCDD2, "Below Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Below")
col_fall_below = input(#FF5252, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Below")
// Calculating
fast_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, fast_length) : ta.ema(src, fast_length)
slow_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, slow_length) : ta.ema(src, slow_length)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal = sma_signal == "SMA" ? ta.sma(macd, signal_length) : ta.ema(macd, signal_length)
hist = macd - signal
hline(0, "Zero Line", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
plot(hist, title="Histogram", style=plot.style_columns, color=(hist>=0 ? (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_above : col_fall_above) : (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_below : col_fall_below)))
plot(macd, title="MACD", color=col_macd)
plot(signal, title="Signal", color=col_signal)
```